# Is it possible to freeze headers on columns and rows in saiku?

Tags: saiku

Is there a feature to freeze headers on rows or/and columns in saiku? I am about to start working on this through css. Is there anyone else working on this feature?

Cheers,
itso

Answer (score 0):

***"Freeze headers on rows or/and columns in saiku"***

you talk in fixed the header of table html when the user use the scroll?